# Delete [PFUser currentUser] after Facebook login

Tags: ios, facebook, parse-platform

I want to give my user the ability to remove their account, thus not showing up in the feeds of other users.

One way I could do this is adding an 'active' column to the 'User' table.

A better way would be to remove their User object from the table. Unfortunately, when I implement code to do so, the app crashes and the following error shows up: 'User cannot be deleted unless they have been authenticated via logIn or signUp'.

Maybe something is wrong with my login code.

```
NSArray *permissionsArray = @[@"email", @"public_profile", @"user_friends"];

[PFFacebookUtils logInWithPermissions:permissionsArray block:^(PFUser *user, NSError *error) {
    if (!user) {
        if (error) {
            UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Oops, error" message:@"Couldn't login at the moment. Try again later." delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:@"Dismiss", nil];
            [alert show];
        }
    }
    else {
        // Send request to Facebook
        [[FBRequest requestForMe] startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
            // handle response
            if (!error) {
                // Parse the data received
                NSDictionary *userData = (NSDictionary *)result;

                [[PFUser currentUser] setObject:[NSNumber numberWithLongLong:[userData[@"id"] longLongValue]] forKey:@"facebook_id"];
                [[PFUser currentUser] setObject:userData[@"name"] forKey:@"name"];
                [[PFUser currentUser] saveInBackground];


                // Go to home screen here
            }
        }];
    }
}];
```

Deleting is done like this:

```
PFObject *userObject = [PFObject objectWithoutDataWithClassName:@"_User" objectId:[PFUser currentUser].objectId];
[userObject deleteInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {
    // back to login view controller
}];
```

Any idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why are you re-fetching the user object when you already have it as `[PFUser currentUser]`? Perhaps you need to delete the `[PFUser currentUser]` object directly? Something like:

```
[[PFUser currentUser] deleteInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {
    // back to login view controller
}];
```

Comment: Thanks, that did the trick. I had no idea `currentUser` returns a `PFObject`.